# Before_destroy: delete many-to-many association unless association.size > 1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, many-to-many, destroy, before-filter

I have a `many-to-many` association between `User` and `Project`, joined by `Participation`.

When a `user` instance gets deleted I want to delete all `user.projects` and `user.participations` IF no other `user` is associated to those `projects`.

I've tried the following, but it seems like the user already has been destroyed by the time the method is run:

```
before_destroy :destroy_all_projects_if_only_user

private
def destroy_all_projects_if_only_user
  self.projects.each do |project|
    unless project.users.size > 1
      project.destroy
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: How do you delete user?

Comment: In the destroy action with `@user.destroy`.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like there are two things you are trying to accomplish: first, destroy the associations in the join table, then destroy the associated objects if they would be orphaned.  Here's one way you could do it:

In your user model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # clear all project associations for this user
  before_destroy { projects.clear }

  # clean up any orphaned projects in the database
  after_destroy { Project.where("id NOT IN (SELECT project_id FROM participations)").destroy_all }
end
```

This approach not only deletes orphaned projects for the user that was just deleted, but any other orphaned projects that might be lingering in your database, as well.